# T four space and the continuous function

Tags: general-topology

Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous surjective closed map. Prove that if X is $T_4$ then Y is $T_4$?

I want to prove this and I want to know what is the difference between $T_4$ space and the normal space.

I started my proof assuming that $C$ closed in $Y$ then $f^{-1}(C)$ would be closed since $f$ is continuous. Then I took an open subset $U$ of $Y$ containing $C$ then I said that $f^{-1}(C)$ is subset of $f^{-1}(U)$ ?? I am not sure about what I wrote here since we have a surjective function?

I will appreaciate any help for this

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $T_4$ is normal and all singletons are closed (So to ensure that $T_4$ implies $T_2$, as separating points then follows from separating their closed singleton sets). Similary $T_3$ is regular plus $T_1$ as well, so that now $T_4 \rightarrow T_3 \rightarrow T_2 \rightarrow T_1$, a nicer hierarchy of properties.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know what is the difference between $T_4$ space and the normal space.

Usually a $T_4$ topological space is a $T_1$ space that it is also normal; however, some authors also define normality including the $T_1$ axiom.

Since $f$ is closed, $Y$ is a $T_1$ space.

Now let $C$ be a closed subset of $Y$ and $U$ an open subset such that $C \subseteq U$, since $f$ is continuous $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed and $f^{-1}(U)$ is open, as you claim $f^{-1}(C) \subseteq f^{-1}(U)$. Then, since $X$ is normal there exists an open set $V$ such that $f^{-1}(C) \subseteq V \subseteq f^{-1}(U)$ and $\bar{V} \subseteq f^{-1}(U)$. Now, $C \subseteq f(V) \subseteq U$ and $f(\bar{V}) \subseteq U$. Let $A = (Y -f(X - V))$. What can you say about $A$ is it open? and what about its closure, is $\bar{A}\subseteq U$?

Comment: Nice it is I think another way to proof that

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $C$ and $D$ are disjoint closed subsets of $Y$. Then $f^{-1}[C]$ and $f^{-1}[D]$ are disjoint (for any $f$) and closed (by continuity of $f$) in $X$, so if $X$ is normal, we find open sets $U,V \subset X$ such that

$$f^{-1}[C] \subseteq U, f^{-1}[D] \subseteq V ,U \cap V = \emptyset$$

Now define $O_1 = Y \setminus f[X\setminus U]$ and similarly $O_2 = Y \setminus f[X\setminus V]$. As $U$ is open, $X \setminus U$ is closed and as $f$ is closed, $f[X\setminus U]$ is closed and so $O_1$, its complement in $Y$ is open in $Y$. The exact same reasoning shows that $O_2$ is open in $Y$ too.

Suppose $ y\in O_1 \cap O_2$. Find some $x \in X$ with $f(x)= y$ as $f$ is onto.

If $x \notin U$ would hold, then $y = f(x) \in f[X \setminus U]$, so $y \notin O_1$, contradiction. So $x \in U$.

Similarly, if $x \notin V$ would hold, then $y = f(x) \in f[X \setminus V]$, so $y \notin O_2$, contradiction. So $x \in V$ as well. This contradicts that $U \cap V =\emptyset$. We conclude that $O_1 \cap O_2 = \emptyset$ as well.

Suppose $y \in C$ and $y \notin O_1$. The latter means that $y \in f[X \setminus U]$ by definition, so there is some $x \in X \setminus U$, such that $f(x) = y$.
But this $x \in f^{-1}[C]$ (as $y = f(x) \in C$), but $x \notin U$. This contradicts $f^{-1}[C] \subseteq U$. So we conclude $C \subseteq O_1$.

Similarly $D \subseteq O_2$, and we finished the proof that $Y$ is normal, as we separated disjoint closed $C$ and $D$ by disjoint open subsets $O_1$ and $O_2$.

So if $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is onto, closed and surjective and $X$ is normal (in the separating closed sets sense) then $Y$ is normal.

If $X$ is $T_1$ (So $\{x\}$ is closed for every $x \in X$) ,$Y$ is $T_1$ as well,as $\{y\} = f[\{x\}]$, for any $x$ with $f(x) = y$ and $f$ is closed.

Normally $T_4$ is defined as normal and $T_1$, so $T_4$ is preserved by combining these two statements.

Comment: wow i really got it properly thank you so so much

Comment: @Mado glad I could help!